# A fraction less than something?

Tags: mathematics, gre

I encountered a question which is phrased:

> A book store stocks 1/5 of its books as fiction works, and **1/3 less
>   than the fiction books as self-help books.** What fraction of books are
>   fiction and self-help books?

I have a problem with the highlighted part. The (1/3) just seems to hang there, without explicitly applying to the number of fiction books.

The solution manual interprets this as:

```
number of self-help books = number of fiction - (1/3 x number of fiction)
```

Is this question phrased correctly?

Comment: I think it's like saying, "X is 10% more than Y." It's clear that "10% of Y more than Y" is meant. That said, I do think the phrasing here is awkward. Linguistic imprecision and awkwardness are annoyingly common in math problems, I've found.

Comment: I would interpret the phrase the same as the solution manual does. (1/3 less than X) means (X - X/3).

Comment: The more I look at it, the more reasonable it seems. I just don't know anymore :)

Comment: I think this is Too Localised. The phrasing is as valid as it can be for such a tortuous context (English isn't really very good as a mathematical language), so you can only interpret it the way the manual solution says. That's to say, if the store has 15 books, 3 of them are fiction. 1/3rd less than 3 is one self-help book, so 4 out of 15 books fall into one or other of those two categories (the *fraction* is thus 4/15). I don't see any other way to read it, but I don't really see the problem - it says *1/3 less **than the fiction books***, so the **1/3** bit isn't just "left hanging".

Comment: @Fumblefingers, I disagree with you only in that 1/3 less than 3 is (3 - ((1/3)*3) => 3 - 1 => 2 and thus the total fraction is 5/15.

Comment: 4/15 was the answer I came up with. But what @Hellion mentions is the actual solution.

Comment: @Hellion, DarkCthulhu: Yes, of course Hellion is right. I forgot to implement the subtraction implied by **less**, and take the intermediate **1** away from the **3**. Nothing to do with language as such though - just me not paying attention to the maths while I was concentrating on fiddling with bold and italic fonts in the comment.

Comment: @ DarkCthulhu: You might find it easier if you read it as *1/3 less than **the number of** fiction books*. But the whole idea of *stocking [some amount of] books **as** [some type of book]* is a bit weird, to my ear. You normally ***classify*** something ***as*** [some type], implying you have some degree of choice about what it is. But in the case of a book store, surely the books already *have* their categorisation before they're even bought in. I don't think *stock as* works in this context.

Comment: Once the context becomes more 'number-orientated' than 'portion-orientated', percentages are the usual language of choice. A more idiomatic phrasing would be: 20% of a book store's stocks are works of fiction, and the number of self-help books in stock is 33 1/3% fewer than the number of fiction books. What percentage of books do fiction and self-help books taken together comprise?

Answer (score 1):

The phrasing is correct and it seems to be precise enough – there seems to be no obvious way to misinterpret it.  Part of the purpose of doing math “word problems” is to develop skill in interpreting what is meant.  But for clearer communication of the intended meaning, as one would use when not posing a word problem, a phrasing like  “1/5 of its books are fiction works, and 2/3 as many as that are self-help books” might be better.

Note that the question as asked cannot be answered, because it does not tell how many of the self-help books are fictional or vice versa.  Those books will be counted twice if we just add 1/5 to 2/15 and give an answer of 1/3.

Comment: I am starting to understand the phrasing. :) The fictional and self-help books as a set are mutually exclusive in this case.